# Twitter/Facebook API for Ruby

Tags: ruby, facebook, twitter

I want to write a Ruby application through which:

1. I can submit tweets to twitter.
2. I can submit a post to facebook.
3. I can manage real-time stats of tweets

Is there any twitter/facebook api for Ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Streams of tweets:**

Tweetmon is a great gem for keeping real-time track of tweets. Here's an example of using it to get a stream of tweets on a specific keyword

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/ruby 

 if ARGV.size==1
   keyword = ARGV.shift
 else
   puts 'tweetmon usage: tweetmon <keyword>'
   exit 1
 end

 require 'yaml'
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'tweetstream'

 config = YAML::load(File.open(File.expand_path('~/.twitter')))
 user =config['username']
 password =config['password']

 TweetStream::Client.new(user,password).track(keyword) do |status|  
   puts "[#{status.created_at}-#{status.user.screen_name}] #{status.text}"
 end
```

To use this gem you need:
     gem sources -a http://gems.github.com
     gem install intridea-tweetstream

**To submit a tweet** is just a HTTP POST - doesn't need any extra libraries to do this.

Comment: GitHub took down it's gem hosting quite some time ago, but if you have an updated RubyGems installation, you should be able to run `sudo gem install tweetstream`, if you get an error that the gem doesn't exits, try to run `gem sources -a "http://gemcutter.org"`.

Answer (score 6):

I use the [Twitter](http://twitter.rubyforge.org/) gem and am quite happy with it.

For Facebook, there is the [Facebooker](http://facebooker.rubyforge.org/) gem.

Answer (score 2):

The Twitter API is a [RESTful web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_web_services). It's completely language agnostic. Use whatever language you want.

Not sure about Facebook.

Comment: Facebook API is also RESTful.

Answer (score 1):

Two more libraries that didn't get mentioned yet:

- twitter4r: http://twitter4r.rubyforge.org/
- Twibot: http://cjohansen.no/en/ruby/twibot_a_microframework_for_twitter_bots_in_ruby

Answer (score 1):

If you're inclined to retain more control over how you use the Twitter and Facebook APIs you can use the [Wrest gem](http://github.com/kaiwren/wrest).

Take a look at the facebook (http://is.gd/bJspX) and twitter (http://is.gd/bJsqV) examples.

Also, while both the Twitter and Facebook APIs are HTTP APIs, they are not RESTful despite their claims to the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this gem, it's really helpful https://github.com/moomerman/twitter_oauth

or just gem install twitter_oauth

Answer (score 1):

MiniFB https://github.com/appoxy/mini_fb is excellent for Facebook API. But in both APIs you can do everything through HTTPParty and OAuth.